# Why does the compiler report such an error？（'width' was not declared in this scope）

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

I am searching for a long time on net. But no use. Please help or try to give some ideas how to achieve this.
I've tried multiple variations of this, but none of them seem to work. Any ideas?

```
 #include <iostream>
  using namespace std;

  class RectangleArea   
 {
           public:
                void SetData (float L,float W);
                float ComputeArea();
                void OutputArea();
           private:
                float length,width,area;

  };

 void RectangleArea::SetData(float L,float W)
  {
       length=L;
       width=W;
  }
 float RectangleArea::ComputeArea()
 {
      area=length*width;
 }
 void RectangleArea::OutputArea()
 {
      cout<<"Area is "<<area<<endl;
 }
int main()
{
RectangleArea Rectangle;
cout<<"input length and width:"<<endl;   //The error appears in this position//
cin>>length>>width;
Rectangle.SetData(length, width);
Rectangle.ComputeArea();
Rectangle.OutputArea();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: The error should be appearing at the line after the position you mentioned. There is no `length` and `width` in the main function; those are private variables of the `RectangleArea` class. You will want to add a `float length, width` before you begin taking input if you want to do what I think you do.

Comment: Also, this has little to do with the [error-handling] tag, which is for things like exceptions in the case of C++. I suggest you read the tag brief before including it just to make sure it is relevant.

Comment: `cin>>length>>width;` -- Let's ask you the same question -- where is `length` and `width` declared?  I don't see it, and neither does the compiler.